# Map child object to base object using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two models *DashboardWidgetModel* and *WidgetModel* which I want to map to single view model *WidgetViewModel*.

**The Association Dashboard Widget Model**

```
        public DashboardWidgetModel()
        {
            public int Id {get;set;}
            public int DashboardId {get;set;}
            public int WidgetId {get;set;}
            public virtual Widget Widget {get;set;}
            public int PositionX{get;set;}
            public int PositionY {get;set;}
        }
```

**The Widget Model**

```
        public WidgetModel()
        {
            public int Id {get;set;}
            public string Name {get;set;}
            public string Desc {get;set;}
            public int P3{get;set;}
            public int P4 {get;set;}
            public int P5 {get;set;}
        }
```

**The Widget View Model**

```
        public WidgetViewModel()
        {
            public int Id {get;set;}
            public string PositionX {get;set;}
            public string PositionY {get;set;}
            public string Name {get;set;}
            public string Desc {get;set;}
            public int P3 {get;set;}
            public int P4 {get;set;}
            public int P5 {get;set;}

        }
```

I am using AutoMapper to handle the mapping for the rest of my application and would like to map all of the properties to a single flat view model.  Problem being `Widgets` is a nested object.

Instead of manually defining every item to map from the child object, is there a way to do this automatically?

```
    public DashboardProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<DashboardToWidget, WidgetViewModel>()
            .ForMember(vm => vm.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.Widget.Name))
            .ForMember(vm => vm.Desc, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.Widget.Desc))
            .ForMember(vm => vm.P3, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.Widget.P3))
            .ForMember(vm => vm.P4, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.Widget.P4))
            .ForMember(vm => vm.P5, opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.Widget.P5)); 

        CreateMap<Widget, WidgetViewModel>();
    }
```

It feels as if I need to map `DashboardWidgetModel` to `WidgetViewModel` then map `WidgetModel` to the same `WidgetViewModel` after, but I'm unsure how to do this or what terminology to use to find the answer.

*Edit (after CSL's answer): I am unable to change property names due to inheritance.*

Answer (score 1):

No need for any custom mappings if you change your destination property names to be prefixed with `Widget`, AutoMapper will automatically work out that you want to reference a Child Property of the Widget Class:

```
public WidgetViewModel()
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string PositionX {get;set;}
    public string PositionY {get;set;}
    public string WidgetName {get;set;}
    public string WidgetDesc {get;set;}
    public int WidgetP3 {get;set;}
    public int WidgetP4 {get;set;}
    public int WidgetP5 {get;set;}
}
```

The mapping will simply become:

```
public DashboardProfile()
{
    CreateMap<DashboardWidgetModel, WidgetViewModel>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks CSL, this works really well.  Unfortunately I am unable to change property names within the ViewModel as it inherits from a base class that a number of partial views rely on.  This will definitely will prove useful elsewhere in the application though!